# Ethernet problems on ASIX AX88772B USB 2.0 Ethernet adapter

Tags: ethernet, chromebook

I have some problems with ethernet on Linux chrubuntu 3.13.0-29-generic.

Network manager shows  the network is connected and the device is recognized, but there is no internet.
Interestingly it sometimes opens google.com and I am able to input queries, but they are very slow and nothing else works.
Here is some info:

```
user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo ifconfig -a
[sudo] password for user: 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 72:b1:b1:c1:d8:46  
          inet addr:129.118.162.17  Bcast:129.118.163.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::70b1:b1ff:fec1:d846/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18700 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2122 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2138423 (2.1 MB)  TX bytes:404200 (404.2 KB)


    user@chrubuntu:~$ lshw -C network
    WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
      *-network               
           description: Wireless interface
           product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
           vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
           logical name: wlan0
           version: 01
           serial: 14:2d:27:b3:2a:6f
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-29-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
           resources: irq:16 memory:e0400000-e047ffff memory:e0480000-e048ffff
      *-network
           description: Ethernet interface
           physical id: 1
           logical name: eth0
           serial: 72:b1:b1:c1:d8:46
           size: 100Mbit/s
           capacity: 100Mbit/s
           capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=asix driverversion=22-Aug-2005 duplex=full firmware=ASIX AX88772B USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=129.118.162.17 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
    WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

**UPD** (netstat-rn and tracepath -n 8 8 8 8):

```
 user@chrubuntu:~$ netstat -rn
 Kernel IP routing table
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
 0.0.0.0         129.118.163.254 0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
 129.118.162.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 eth0

 user@chrubuntu:~$ tracepath -n 8.8.8.8
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  129.118.163.254                                       1.894ms 
 1:  129.118.163.254                                       1.899ms 
 2:  129.118.251.29                                        1.994ms 
 3:  129.118.4.246                                         2.197ms 
 4:  129.118.4.233                                         2.707ms asymm  5 
 5:  129.118.4.238                                         2.932ms 
 6:  12.249.227.125                                       10.755ms asymm  7 
 7:  no reply
 8:  no reply
 9:  no reply
10:  no reply
11:  no reply
12:  no reply
13:  no reply
14:  no reply
15:  no reply
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
21:  no reply
22:  no reply
23:  no reply
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
```

I tried to update the driver (downloaded the latest one from ASIX website) , but it seems I updated it to an older version (22-Aug-2005) and it did not help.

When I Ping 8.8.8.8 all the packages are lost.

Exactly the same internet cord works on another computer(desktop) running standard Ubuntu 14.04.It also works on the same chromebook when I use Chrome OS.

Any thoughts?

Comment: probably a routing issues post `netstat -rn` and `tracepath -n 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the post. Any ideas of how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with your ISP. The packets are leaving your computer/network and then get dropped half way through. Call up your provider and tell them to fix their stuff

Comment: OOpps didn't see the part where you say it works on the other computer. Very odd. Unless your ISP binds your IP to a MAC hmmm plug the cord into a working computer and post `ifconfig -a` and `tracepath -n 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Do you set your IP manually? Or it got it auto (via DHCP)? Something funny is going on between AT&T and Texas Tech University for that route

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found the problem. First I ran the same commands on the computer where the internet worked and the output was the same. Looks like some firewall in between me and AT&T blocks access to 8.8.8.8 (and many other ips I tried to ping) and it was used as a primary dns. I edited my resolv.conf before since the dns that was written there did not work with other internet connection. I copied the resolv.conf from another computer and everything works now!